# Content after fixed position

Tags: html, css

The position is something that really confuses me as per the name, `absolute` or `relative`. I am trying to create a simple layout, where the header says static, and If something is added or deleted more/less in `.subheading` the `.filter` class adjust itself, but now my `.filter` the class is starting from the top, whereas It should be relative to `.subheading`.

What am I doing wrong?

https://codepen.io/codearts/pen/GvEoBZ

```css
.header{
  position:fixed;
  background:black;
  height:60px;
  width:100%
}
.subheader{
  height:40px;
  background:grey;
  position:absolute;
  top:60px;
  width:100%;
}
.filter{
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="header"></div>
      <div class="subheader">
        This can be either
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filter">
        <div class="col-6">
          This can be col-1
        </div>
          <div class="col-6">
        This can be col-2
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as both of your subheader and filter are positioned absolute, you are suppose to set top as 100px(60+40) to your filter to set below your subheader.

Comment: It will make them stick at one place e.g If i make my subheading text too big, It won't push down filter but cover it. @RaJeshRiJo

Comment: ok, so are you going to keep both header and subheader as fixed on top?

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo Just the first one. `.subheading` can have longer or smaller text but will scroll with page.

Comment: check below answer and try that fiddle. hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am trying to solve your problem, not sure this will help on your situation, have a try on below [fidder][1].

What you are suppose to do is put all three div into a single container and set padding-top as fixed header's height. And leave subheader and filter as it is. Need not positioning them.

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/5mra9tsv/2/
```

Comment: That worked but still wondering how does `fixed` position works.

Comment: It's simple, whatever you positioned as fixed, it will remain fixed to the display. It won't get changed it's  position when scroll. Here header positioned fixed on top by specifying top:0, Means header has to be positioned fixed from top 0px.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `.filters` and `.subheader` to be in `position:absolute`.

It's more complex than that but in short, `absolute` position allow you to remove an element from the flow and place it regarding its parent. But to do so, its parent need to be in `position: relative`, but I don't think you'd need it in this case.

Simply add a margin-top to `.subheader` and it will do the trick :)

*(actually as un Johannes's comment)*

**EDIT**

Solution in fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/derdnjzs/

Comment: If I remove`.subheading` it will leave a space in between with margin-top

Comment: Okay, so you need to seperate the `position: fixed` header from the rest.
Put `.header` in his own wrapper and `.subheader` & `.filters` in another container.

Actually, the fiddle from RaJesh could work either : https://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/5mra9tsv/2/